# heroku-buildpack-static with https_only set to true in static.json does not appear to force http to https on my heroku app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, gatsby, static-site

I've deployed a gatsbyjs site with heroku using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static and my understanding is that if https_only is set to true in the static.json file then it should be forcing http requests to https.

static.json

```
{
  "root": "public/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "https_only": true,
   ...
   ...
}
```

When logging into heroku and viewing the deployed static.json it is also set to true. I don't imagine it is from caching of the buildpack?

The site is http://ltnetwork.herokuapp.com/

Thanks